# Excel - Display certain information when interacting with a graph

Tags: excel

Is there a way to, if the user clicks on a graph or perhaps just hovers over it, it display selected data?

Imagine a graph with 3 bars. The bars may, arbitrarily, represent the number of people who drive, walk, or use bikes.

If I were to click on the bar representing those who ride bikes, is there a way to display the names of those people, for example (given that the names are associated with the data used to make the graph in rows elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using **Chart Events**. Events are enabled for chart sheets by default, but for an embedded chart you can study this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211434%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The same page includes this link for [Chart Object Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211346%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

This requires programming using Excel VBA.

Comment: I figured it would be possible in VBA. I have not yet taken the time to learn it yet. Perhaps now is better a time than ever. Thank you for the link!

Comment: You are welcome. Recording lots of macros and examining the code will get the ball rolling! This won't help with Chart Events though - you'll need to defer that a little while. John Walkenbach's Excel VBA for Dummies is a good book.